# Cannot pass JS variable to PHP using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, w3c-geolocation

I am trying to get current location of user.

I have JS script to get current Latitude and Longitude with AJAX to send js variables to index.php.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if ("geolocation" in navigator){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
            var userLat = position.coords.latitude;
            var userLong = position.coords.longitude;
            console.log(userLong);
            console.log(userLat);

            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: 'index.php',
              data: {
              userLat : userLat,
              userLong : userLong
              },
              success: function(data)
                {
                  console.log(data);

                }

            });

    });
}else{
    console.log("Browser doesn't support geolocation!");
}});
```

Then I am trying to do this in my index.php:

```
echo $_POST['userLat'];
echo $_POST['userLong'];
```

Nothing shows up. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your browser's debugging tools, are there any errors on the console?  What network requests are made and what data is included in those requests?  When you debug, is the AJAX call made at all?  What exactly is the server's response?

Comment: It shows correct output for:

    console.log(userLong);
    console.log(userLat);

No other errors. Also for console,log(data) it shows entire page code, I am not sure why.

Comment: Well, it's showing whatever is returned by that AJAX request.  If `index.php` returns the entire page, then it'll show the entire page.  Where exactly are you looking for the AJAX values?  Aren't you checking the console log response?

Comment: Yep, I am checking console output for index.php. like I said, it shows correct values in console output for userLong and userLat but when console.log(data) is called it shows entire page's code instead of data that was sent with AJAX. I am not sure why this is happening.

Comment: `"it shows correct values in console output"` - Then what exactly is the problem?  You're logging to the console, and nothing else.  And the correct data is in the console.  So what's wrong?  What were you expecting to happen?  It shows the entire page because that's what's in the response when you request the page.  Is there any reason why it shouldn't be doing this?

Comment: I tested this code and it seemed to work exactly as expected. What were you expecting differently?

Comment: The idea is to transfer variable userLat and userLong to php variables, this doesnt happen.

Comment: @ValentinM: How have you verified that this doesn't happen?  There are no "PHP variables" used anywhere in the question.  The code you show works.  The behavior you describe is *exactly* what we would expect it to do.  You haven't described or demonstrated any actual problem.

Comment: Basically when I try to echo $_POST['userLat']; it doesn't shw anything. That's the problem.

Comment: @ValentinM: Earlier you stated that the entire HTML code is logged to the console.  When you look in that HTML code, do you see that echo-ed output?  Not on the current page, but in what's logged to the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Nothing shows up.

And that's **correct** you will never get any thing by browsing index.php because there is no POST at this time , AJAX is internal and the only way to show a result from index.php is in the page that you send from it an ajax  call.

At this :

```
success: function(data)
            {
              console.log(data);

            }
```

you could control where to show your data that comes from index.php by , for example `alert(data)`  or `document.getElementById("someelement").innerHTML=data;` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

It might help to define and return a `dataType` for the ajax.

add this to your list of `ajax` options

```
 dataType: 'json',
```

Then in index.php encode and echo a json string. Remove the lines

```
echo $_POST['userLat'];
echo $_POST['userLong'];
```

replace them with

```
echo json_encode($_POST);
```

The `console.log(data);` in the success function should show an object with two items: 'userlat' and 'userLong' and associated values for each. Or it should if `$_POST` had those two items.

If you want the browser screen to update you will have to take `data` and use it to modify the DOM.

Comment: now my AJAX code looks like this:

$.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                  url: 'index.php',
                  dataType: 'json',
                  data: {
                  userLat : userLat,
                  userLong : userLong
                  },
                  success: function(data)
                    {
                      console.log(data);

                    }

                });

and in index.php I have echo json_decode('$_POST');

Still doesnt "echo" anything and console log for console.log(data); is empty now.

Comment: Should be `json_encode`, not `json_decode`. Also,remove the single quotes around `$_POST`. Use this `echo json_encode($_POST);`

Comment: The `echo` from a function handling an ajax request will not be sent to the browser output. It is sent to the `success` function of your ajax statement.